# How to add a DynamoDB global secondary Index via Python/Boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, python-ggplot

Is it possible to add a Global Secondary Index to and existing DynamoDB table AFTER it has been created?  I am using Python 3.x with Boto3 and have not been able to find any examples of them being added to the table after it was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes it is possible to add a Global Secondary Index (`GSI`) after the table is created.

However, it can take a long time for the change to come into effect, because building the `GSI` requires a table scan.

In the case of `boto3`, have a look at [the documentation for `update_table`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_table)

For example, you try something like this:

```py
response = client.update_table(
    TableName = 'YourTableName',
    # ...snip...
    GlobalSecondaryIndexUpdates=[
        {
            'Create': {
                'IndexName': 'YourGSIName',
                'KeySchema': [
                    {
                        'AttributeName': 'YourGSIFieldName',
                        'KeyType': 'HASH'
                    }
                ],
                'Projection': {
                    'ProjectionType': 'ALL'
                },
                'ProvisionedThroughput': {
                    'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,
                    'WriteCapacityUnits': 1
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    # ...snip...
)
```

Comment: It appears as if this method works well, but if you are not careful you can create multiple global secondary indexes with the same KeySchema.  This would waste resources and provide no value.  So this routine should probably check to see if an index already exists before creating a new GS index.

Comment: Yes, personally I'd recommend using a CF template (or similar) to avoid that scenario